# Angular 2 - angular-cli - Bootstrap Hamburguer Icon Not Working

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, firebase-hosting

I am currently having problems getting the bootstrap icon to work on mobile devices. When I click on it, nothing happens (icon grey's out). It works when I test it locally, but when I deploy web app to firebase, it does not work there. Here is the link: https://mccleaningservices-55819.firebaseapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the bootstrap js added in your index.html? I believe the hamburger toggle requires javascript so I'm wondering if it's not there, or if there is a conflict